# Looking for a simple checkout plugin

Tags: plugins, forms

I want to sell tickets to an event on my wordpress site. I don't want to use a huge shop or partner up with ticketmaster etc.

What I want is let the customer decide how many tickets of a certain category they want and make a reservation, no payment involved. It should be able to display the total amount due and a nice message on submit.

Is there a simple plugin without much overhead? What should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an open ended question I'll just give you a basic rundown of how I would do it.

It seems that you would not need a cart plugin at all as you are not requiing a payment method. Therefore, I would use a simple contact form and have it send a copy to the guest and the admin. The would allow you to get the information you needed without worrying about payment.

There are a TON of Contact form plugins, If you are looking for free ones I recommend [cforms II](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/), [contactform-7](http://contactform7.com) and [Dagon Design's php Mailer](http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/secure-form-mailer-plugin-for-wordpress/). In that order. The hardest part with these forms will be getting your total to update with the amount of tickets. I think cforms II will have the most out of the box function to do this. You could also use a few lines of jQuery to do this such as:

```
$("#ticket_number").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("ticket_price").val(value*20); //assuming $20 is the price
    }).keyup();
```

There are also commercial plugin solutions such as [Gravity forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) which will handle the pricing fields and JavaScript for you.

Hope that gets you on the right track.